# Angular template interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date, format

Angular version 11

I have a template which uses a method of the typescript file which returns the current date time.

The thing is that if in the interpolation of the template I call this method, the first time I render the page, it works properly, but after 1 minute, the value should change to the next minute... which it does not....

How can I make that angular refreshes the template if the result of this method is different ?

template:

```
<span id="date-time">
   {{getCurrentDateTime()}}
</span>
```

Method in the typescript file:

```
// This method returns the current date-time of a timezone
public getDateTimeForSiteDifferentTimeZone(): string {
    const momentString = moment.tz(this.timeZone).format('DD MMM y, hh:mm A');
    return momentString;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atmtqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html ?

Comment: this could work. however angular should render the component if the content of it changes (using the method Directly in the interpolation, instead of the property)

Comment: "_angular should render the component if the content of it changes_" what do you mean? where's the content change?

Comment: See the comment I added in the answer below please :)

Comment: I still don't understand how you invoke this method. You're saying "if you call it in two minutes" but how are you calling the method?

Comment: in the template in the interpolation.... my example in the question shows how

Comment: You would want that method to be called every minute. Angular can't know when the content should be updated so you need to tell Angular when to update the content. That's what the setInterval does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

1. In your template, declare a variable `time`:

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  time = getCurrentDateTime()
...
}
```

2. Interpolate `time`

```html
<span id="date-time">
   {{time}}
</span>
```

3. Create an `ngOnInit` function and fill it with a `setInterval` for 60000ms (1 minute, because your time seems to display only minute). when it fires, update the `time` variable.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  setInterval(() => {time = getCurrentDateTime()}, 60000)
}
```

Comment: its a method which you can see in my question.... if you call this method now, it will answer: 26 Apr 2021, 03:27 PM.... but if you call this method in 2 mins, will answer this 26 Apr 2021, 03:27 PM


So technically nothing makes this method changes, it changes it self

Comment: Alright, updating the question, please wait

Comment: You can't call the function again like @eko says. A function only runs once and you can't say if the content is different without running it again and again, which is not a nice thing to do

Comment: What I'm doing here is forcing javascript to run it again and again, which updates the time every 60 seconds

Answer (score -1):

declare control to manage string to show time

```
timeControl = new FormControl(this.getDateTimeForSiteDifferentTimeZone()); // initialize with curren time, if your get error there use it inside ngOnInit
```

ngOnInit

```
// remember to delete subscription, I use  @ngneat/until-destroy library
interval(60000).pipe(

            untilDestroyed(this), 
            tap(() => {
                this.timeControl.setValue(this.getDateTimeForSiteDifferentTimeZone());
            })
        ).subscribe();
```

template

```
<span id="date-time">
   {{timeControl.value}}
</span>
```

I dont now how to use your function getCurrentDate(), in this example I use directly your function to generate current date using moment.

**UPDATE to consider with setInterval solution:**
Please remember to use clearInterval in the  ngOnDestroy component's method, otherwise I think it would stay running indefinitely even if you exit the component, and it could generate a problem for you if generate setInterval function every time you render that component. that problem do no occurs with observable solution and managing subscription.